# Two non-clustered indexes with the same attributes as key

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have two indexes like this.

Index #1:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [index1] 
ON [dbo].[table1] ([column1], [column2], [column3])
INCLUDE ([column4], [column5], [column6]) WITH (ONLINE = ON)
```

Index #2:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [index2] 
ON [dbo].[table1] ([column2], [column1], [column3]) 
INCLUDE ([column4], [column5]) WITH (ONLINE = ON)
```

Question is: since both indexes have the same columns (but with a different sequence) and `index1` includes more columns that `index2`, would you say that `index2` could be removed and all the queries that it was serving would be served by `index1`?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: No. The order matters. `c1, c2, c3` can do everything `c1, c2` can do, but cannot do everything `c2, c1` can do (unless you always use both columns in every lookup). If you have a phone book sorted by first name then last name, it cannot replace your phone book sorted by last name then first name (unless you are always looking up one specific combination of first name and last name).

Answer (score 1):

*Would you say that index2 could be removed and all the queries that it was serving would be served by index1?*

No, index1 will not serve the queries that used index2.

Index is sorted based on the columns/keys selected. So different key orders, regardless if multiple indexes contain the same set of columns as index key, will be used differently by the query optimizer.

But having duplicate indexes (indexes with the same set of columns/keys) is not optimal. I would identify the queries that use the indexes and rearrange the join conditions and where clause predicates so that it would use one index and can therefore eliminate the duplicate index.

Comment: "rearranging the join conditions and where clause predicates" does not help anything.